# Как проверить строку на корректность

Tags: php

В С# есть функция `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`, которая проверяет, является ли строка пустой или с одними пробелами. Вопрос, как в php проверить, является ли введённая строка корректной (корректная строка - строка, содержащая символы помимо невидимых)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330371/php-equivalent-to-c-sharp-string-isnullorempty-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала очистить строку от невидимых символов с помощью `trim()`, а потом проверить, что она не нулевой длины